# Writing to output window of Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, debugging

I am trying to write a message to the output window for debugging purposes. I searched for a function like Java's `system.out.println("")`. I tried `Debug.Write`, `Console.Write`, and `Trace.Write`. It does not give an error, but it does not print anything either.

"Define DEBUG constant" and "Define TRACE constant" options are checked.

Menu *Tools* → *Options* → *Debugging* → *"Redirect all Output Window text to the Immediate Window"* option is not checked.

Configuration: Active (Debug)

Note: I created a project with the wizard as "Windows Forms Application" if relevant. I have no idea where to look.

Comment: Since this is an older post, I'll add this as a comment for those who stumble across the question.  Instead of actually changing code, you can also use special breakpoints called tracepoints.  See [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/232dxah7(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: Just a reminder that Debug.WriteLine() will only work when running in Debug.  That means running it with F5 and not CTRL-F5. This is easy to miss.

Comment: That's true, but a handy tool is [DebugView](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/bb896647.aspx) which shows all output to the debug stream when running outside of the debugger

Comment: If you are trying to write output from a unit test running under the Visual Studio test framework the rules are a little different, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11209639/can-i-write-into-console-in-a-unit-test-if-yes-why-the-console-window-is-not-o) for details.

Comment: Just to add on the comment @kirk.burleson made; if you use `Debug.Write` in a library, and you build the library in release mode (which is often the case with nuget packages), then it won't log even if you run your tests/application in debug mode. I would suggest `Trace.Write` as an alternative

Answer (score 924, accepted):

Add the `System.Diagnostics` namespace, and then you can use `Debug.WriteLine()` to quickly print a message to the output window of the IDE. For more details, please refer to these:

- *[How to trace and debug in Visual C#](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/815788)*
- *[A Treatise on Using Debug and Trace classes, including Exception Handling](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3008/A-Treatise-on-Using-Debug-and-Trace-classes-includ)*

Comment: Thank you. I assume there is no way to write to output if i start without debugging (ctrl-f5) right?

Comment: I guess you're looking for this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562590/c-sharp-net-how-to-display-a-message-in-the-output-window-without-being-in-debu

Comment: Thanks again but that is not worked for me. Trace does not print in without debuging mode even if TRACE constant defined.

Comment: Just ran a small app here, works fine for me. Perhaps there is a small glitch in your environment?

Comment: This is my test code; http://pastebin.com/b7P0bYEa It is pretty simple but still nothing. I will try it on another system.

Answer (score 195):

This will write to the debug output window:

```
using System.Diagnostics;

Debug.WriteLine("Send to debug output.");
```

Comment: For me this "outputs" to the Immediate window

Comment: I tried this on a set of unit tests. I debugged the selected test, but there was nothing of what I tried to print out in the debug window.

Comment: This does output to the Debug window, however, only after I close the web page.  I would like an immediate display when I execute the code.  Wait a minute - I found that the output window is hidden while the code is executing.  If I display the window, my output is there.

Answer (score 83):

```
Debug.WriteLine
```

is what you're looking for.

If not, try doing this:

Menu *Tools* → *Options* → *Debugging* → uncheck *Send Output to Immediate*.

Comment: Possibly Debug.Write() is not inserting the carriage return, so messages are getting buffered up?

Comment: I was not seeing the Debug.WriteLine("String") until after I did what Micah said. `Tools|Options|Debugging uncheck Send Output to Immediate`

Comment: I think in the later versions the check box is "Redirect all Output Window text to Immediate Window"

Comment: in VS 2015 it's called: "Redirect all Output Window text to the Immediate Window", just in case, some had to look for 5 mins to find the appropriate setting :) - I was scrolling up and down to find an optiona starting with "Send..." :)

Answer (score 32):

For me, only the **Trace** namespace and not the Debug one worked:

```
System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("message");
```

I'm working in a C# project under Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: I'm using VS 2013 Professional and attempting to get output from a unit test using the Visual Studio unit test framework. It appears the test harness captures and redirects Debug.WriteLine but not Trace.WriteLine. And you won't see Trace output either unless you debug the tests (not just run them).

Answer (score 16):

You may be looking for

```
MessageBox.Show("A message")
```

or

```
Debug.WriteLine("A message")
```

Comment: `MessageBox.Show()` can be very annoying when you want to write multiple values for debugging purposes.

Comment: The Question was "Writing to output window of Visual Studio?" not to a message box.

Comment: @AmirTwito A message box is an output window.

Comment: Yes you right, but the question was "Writing to output window of Visual Studio?" and not to a simple message box using this code: MessageBox.Show()

Comment: @ProfK The *Visual Studio Output Window* is a very specific GUI element of the specific program, and `MessageBox.Show` does not write to it.

Answer (score 14):

The call

```
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("message");
```

fails when working with [.NET Core](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework#.NET_Core) (V 1.0 or 1.1).

We are supposed to create and use a logger from `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging`, but that log only appears in the dotnet.exe popup console window, not in Visual Studio's Output window.

Comment: So Debug.WriteLine(), Console.WriteLine() and Trace.WriteLine() are not outputting anything in Output for .Net Core? Any way to use some sort of simple logging without having to write a Logclass? Have searched in Tools > Options > Debugging and checked the "Show output from:" for possible solutions.

Answer (score 8):

For debugging purposes, the `System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine()` command will not be compiled into the release version of your code unless you have debug listeners.  It writes to all trace listeners which includes the VS output window when running in Debug mode.

For a Console application. `Console.WriteLine()` would work but the output would still be generated in the release version of your binary.

Debug output should also appear in the normal output window when debugging tests; whereas, console.writeline output does not (but can be found in the test output window.)

Answer (score 5):

This requires a third party framework, namely [Serilog](https://serilog.net/), but I've nonetheless found it to be a *very* smooth experience with getting output to some place I can see it.

You first need to install Serilog's [Trace sink](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-trace). Once installed, you need to set up the logger like this:

```
Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .MinimumLevel.Verbose()
    .WriteTo.Trace()
    .CreateLogger();
```

(You can set a different minimum level or set it to a config value or any of the normal Serilog functionality. You can also set the `Trace` logger to a specific level to override configs, or however you want to do this.)

Then you just log messages normally and they show up in your Output window:

```
Logger.Information("Did stuff!");
```

This doesn't seem like such a big deal, so let me explain some additional advantages. The biggest one for me was that I could **simultaneously log to both the Output window and the console**:

```
Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .MinimumLevel.Verbose()
    .WriteTo.Trace()
    .WriteTo.Console(standardErrorFromLevel: LogEventLevel.Error)
    .CreateLogger();
```

This gave me great flexibility in terms of how I consumed output, without having to duplicate all my calls to `Console.Write` with `Debug.Write`. When writing the code, I could run my command line tool in Visual Studio without fear of losing my output when it exited. When I had deployed it and needed to debug something (and didn't have Visual Studio available), the console output was readily available for my consumption. The same messages can also be logged to a file (or any other kind of sink) when it's running as a scheduled task.

The bottom line is that using Serilog to do this made it really easy to dump messages to a multitude of destinations, ensuring I could always readily access the output regardless of how I ran it.

It also requires very minimal set up and code.

Comment: Serilog now also has a "debug" sink at https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-debug that functions in a similar way, but has slightly nicer formatting :-) HTH!

Comment: Why not make a .net public(may be static) method and put there everything you need like  Console.Write or Debug.Write etc and use it everywhere?

Comment: @Saulius "The same messages can also be logged to a file (or any other kind of sink) when it's running as a scheduled task. The bottom line is that using Serilog to do this made it really easy to dump messages to a multitude of destinations, ensuring I could always readily access the output regardless of how I ran it."

Answer (score 3):

```
Debug.Print("text here")
```

or

```
Console.WriteLine("text here")
```

Answer (score 2):

This is not an answer to the original question. But since I found this question when searching for a means of interactively dumping object data, I figured others may benefit from mentioning this very useful alternative.

I ultimately used the Command Window and entered the `Debug.Print` command, as shown below. This printed a memory object in a format that can be copied as text, which is all I really needed.

```
> Debug.Print <item>

  id: 1
  idt: null
  igad: 99
  igbd: 99
  gl_desc: "New #20"
  te_num: "1-001-001-020"
```

Comment: Yep. Or when you want to get the JSON from a model to supply to a colleague `System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(response));`

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me in Visual Studio 2015:

```
OutputDebugStringW(L"Write this to Output window in VS14.");
```

Read the documentation for OutputDebugStringW [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363362(v=vs.85).aspx).

[image]
Note that this method only works if you are debugging your code (`debug mode`)

Comment: Is that C++? The question is tagged [tag:C#].

Comment: 1/ The example is C++, yes,
but the Win32 API that is mentioned is not C++, it's plain C.

2/ In theory we should be able to call it from any language,
but I tried importing it with `/*using System.Runtime.InteropServices;*/
[DllImport("Kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
static extern void OutputDebugStringW(string lpOutputString);`
and sadly, it did not work as intended (it did not print in the Debug output window of the C# project like `System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine()` would).

Answer (score 0):

For anyone using NCrunch, Debug output is redirected to the NCrunch 'Trace Output' window.