# Launching Console before Unit Test runs and write output

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, console-application

I have a sample unit/functional test example below.

What I want is that, launching Console before tests runs and outputting Console.WriteLine into this console.

[image]

```
public class User
        {
            public string UserName { get; set; }
        }
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestUserInitialize()
        {
            // Launch Console, and see Console.WriteLine output here?
            User user = new User();
            InitializeUser(user);
        }

        private void InitializeUser(User user)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Checking user: " + user.UserName);
            Assert.IsTrue(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(user.UserName));
        }
```

Currently I can do `Debug.WriteLine` to see output in Visual Studio, but I would like to make it easier to track in separate console window. Also it will help to execute console examples given on internet, if they are already using `Console.WriteLine`.

Is there any easy way to do this?

Comment: I thought you have to create separate classes for unit tests. And then you can use static constructor of those to initialize your test environment, no?

Comment: I just throw dummy example here. I can do that in real life cases. My main problem is that, when I pick and run a unit test, output to be shown in a new console.

Comment: You may know these bits already, but if you don't, might help :)  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11209639/can-i-write-into-console-in-a-unit-test-if-yes-why-the-console-window-is-not-o