# What is the alternative to Debug.WriteLine for Xamarin Forms PCL in Visual Studio 2017 Community Edition

Tags: xamarin, uwp, xamarin.forms, xamarin.uwp

It seems that Debug.WriteLine does not work in Visual Studio 2017 Community Edition, as discussed in the following link: [Console.WriteLine does not output to Output Window in VS 2017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42907667/console-writeline-does-not-output-to-output-window-in-vs-2017).

Can anyone suggest an alternative for a Xamarin Forms PCL?
When I look at the Debug object from the PCL I only see methods for WriteLine, so I am struggling to see how to attach to a different Listener.

When I look at the the Xamarin documentation for the System.Diagnostics namespace it lists lots of methods and classes that I don't seem to have access to from within my PCL.  For example, the 'TraceListener' class is missing. Is that correct behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

`System.Diagnostic.Debug.WriteLine()` works fine for me in a PCL project, a .NET Standard project, and Xamarin.Android/Xamarin.iOS projects using Visual Studio 2017.

Have you tried it yourself?

`System.Console.WriteLine()` however does not work in a PCL project, though that has nothing to do with the IDE you are using and has more to do with [how PCL projects work](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/pcl/introduction_to_portable_class_libraries/#What_is_a_Portable_Class_Library), but does work in a Xamarin.Android/Xamarin.iOS project. If you are wanting use `System.Console.WriteLine()` in a PCL project you can tap into the native code by various methods. One of those would be a `DependencyService.Get<>()`.

Create the following classes:

PCL:

```
public interface IPlatformHelpers {
    void WriteLine(string text);
}
```

iOS & Android:

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(PlatformHelpers))]

namespace App.<iOS | Android> {

    public class PlatformHelpers : IPlatformHelpers {

        public void WriteLine(string text) {
            System.Console.WriteLine(text);
        }
    }
}
```

Now in your PCL you can do this:

```
IPlatformHelpers helper = DependencyService.Get<IPlatformHelpers>();

helper.WriteLine("Angry BLAH!");
```

Interestingly, it appears that `System.Console.WriteLine()` might be available in a .NET Standard project (at least for .NET Standard 1.3+) though I have not actually tried it out myself yet.

Comment: Yes I have surely tested it. What version of Visual Studio are you using?  I think the problem might be peculiar to Visual Studio 2017 Community Edition, as discussed in the link I mentioned above.

Comment: Your dependency service approach might be the workaround I need, and seems to work for an Android project.

Indeed, in the Android implementation I can use either 'System.Console.WriteLine' or 'Android.Util.Log.Debug'.
They both produce output in the VS Output window.

However, I can't find anything to work in a UWP project.  
There doesn't seem to be an equivalent of 'System.Console.WriteLine' that I can find in UWP.
If use 'System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine' in the UWP implementation I don't get any output.

Any ideas?

Comment: @AntWaters I am running VS 2017 Professional and do not have experience with UWP. Have you tried using `Trace.WriteLine()`? Also `Debug.WriteLine()` and `Trace.WriteLine()` are controlled by what is configured in the project properties. Right-click your UWP Project -> Properties -> Build -> then look for **Define DEBUG constant** (which should be checked for DEBUG configurations and unchecked for RELEASE configurations) and **Define TRACE constant** (which should be check for both DEBUG and RELEASE configurations). You say "there doesn't seem to be an equivalent", does that mean it wont build?

Comment: Thanks @hvaughan3 for the suggestions but no progress.  The two properties were already checked.  yes, I mean that if I try to use `Console.WriteLine` in the UWP project it won't compile, and intellisense can't find any reference to include.  The same applies to `Trace`.  Conversely, `Debug.WriteLine` is found, and compiles, but doesn't produce any output.