# visual studio 2017 community doesnt allow Console.WriteLine()

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017

thanks to

[Console.WriteLine does not output to Output Window in VS 2017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42907667/console-writeline-does-not-output-to-output-window-in-vs-2017)

I have read that VS 2017 ( Community ) does not have "Hosting Process" removing the ability to use Console.WriteLine("");

However, I have also read from the developer community that this issue has been resolved in an update.

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/46776/c-consolewriteline-no-longer-outs-to-vs-output-win.html

I have just downloaded the latest version 'March 05, 2019 -- Visual Studio 2017 version 15.9.8 Servicing Update' and this is still happening.

Does anyone know a way to fix this or should I just revert back to VS 2015.

Thanks

Comment: Strange. I'm currently using VS Community 2017 Version 15.7.1 and everything is working fine.

Comment: You can still use console.writeline() for consoleapplications, it just doesn't show up in the output-pane of vs anymore. if you used it for debugging infos you can use "trace" instead

Comment: For writing to Visual Studio you could use `Debug.WriteLine`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so I used VS2017 and still using it
just make sure that you have used `System` namespace

```
using System;
```

or use

```
System.Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");
```

Visual Studio can't disable or enable `Console.WriteLine` because it's a something of compiler's staff, not Visual Studio's stuff or, to be clear, it's one of .NET libraries.

See: [System Namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system?view=netframework-4.7.2)